# How to make the homepage only displayed the main domain?

Tags: hyperref, urls, cv, awesome-cv

How to make the CV to display my homepage as

```
www.example.com
```

but the actual link is

```
www.example.com/google-analysis-tracking
```

so that click count can be tracked? It uses a custom built command `\homepage{www.example.com}` so hyperrref can't be used.

[Also asked on its GitHub](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/issues/180)

Comment: Can you provide a simple MWE?

Comment: This is hard coded in the template and cannot be changed without changing the class file according to the license and copyright conditions.

Comment: @Johannes_B Would you like to post your comment from  https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/issues/180#issuecomment-353936423 as an answer to this question?

Answer (score 1):

It is easy with the `hyperref` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\href{www.example.com/google-analysis-tracking}{www.example.com}

\end{document}
```

`colorlinks=true` makes links coloured, not boxed.

Comment: It uses a custom built command `\homepage{www.example.com}` so hyperrref can't be used.

Comment: @Ooker And do you want to explain us what `it` means? (MWE)

Comment: This is hard coded in the template and cannot be changed without changing the class file according to the license and copyright conditions.

Comment: https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/issues/180#issuecomment-353936423